# (C#) Error with building multiple target frameworks: "Cannot open 'MyApi.dll' for writing"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, nswag, target-framework

I am following [this guide](https://blog.sanderaernouts.com/autogenerate-api-client-with-nswag) to automatically generate an API client with NSwag. But this client needs to support multiple target frameworks:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.2;net452;net462;net472;net48</TargetFrameworks>
```

When I try to build this client, I get multiple errors like this:

> (CS2012) Cannot open 'MyApi.dll' for writing -- 'The process cannot access the file 'MyApi.dll' because it is being used by another process.'

I suspect this is because each framework is building asynchronously and the DLL produced from my API is trying to be read by each process. How can I fix this issue / make each target framework build synchronously?

Comment: Check for setting `AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath=false` in csproj. If it's exists, try change to true.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Maradik . I didn't have that setting present, so I tried adding it with value set to true. This unfortunately didn't work. Nor did changing it to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found a solution. My lack of understanding around [the guide](https://blog.sanderaernouts.com/autogenerate-api-client-with-nswag) I was reading and the build process meant I wasn't asking the right questions.

I had this build target specified in my .csproj (as directed in the guide):

```
<Target Name="NSwag" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild" Condition="'$(GenerateCode)'=='True' ">
  <Exec Command="$(NSwagExe_Core22) run nswag.json /variables:Configuration=$(Configuration)" />
</Target>
```

This target was **running for each target framework** I had specified in my `<TargetFrameworks>` tag. This was the task that was running in parallel to itself and causing the error from my question.

After a LOT more googling, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46675782/5358731) and (consequently [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54478860/5358731)) which gave me the solution I needed:

> On multi target frameworks I use `BeforeTargets="DispatchToInnerBuilds"` so my custom command is only exeuted once before every build

So my final build target was as simple as this:

```
<Target Name="NSwag" BeforeTargets="DispatchToInnerBuilds" Condition="'$(GenerateCode)'=='True' ">
  <Exec Command="$(NSwagExe_Core22) run nswag.json /variables:Configuration=$(Configuration)" />
</Target>
```

It should also be noted that this solution might not work for all people looking for their build targets to run once per build. See [this issue comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2781#issuecomment-350118208) that provides a similar answer but with more detail about multi-project solutions.